# neovimでのpython環境について

Tags: python, python3, vim

neovimでpython環境を構築しようとしたところ．

```
pip install neovim
```

コマンドを打ったところ

```
Command "c:\users\win2k\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\win2k\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-673_0mi5\\pyuv\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\win2k\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-o5x6r1zi\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\win2k\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-673_0mi5\pyuv\
```

のようなエラーが表示され，neovim上で:echo has('python3')と打つと0が帰ってきてしまいます．
どのような変更を行うと解決できますか

Answer (score 1):

エラーメッセージをみると`pyuv`のコンパイルに失敗しています。Windowsでpython3.5以降のパッケージのCのソースコードをコンパイルするためには、`Visual C++ 14.0 compiler`が必要になります。Build Tools for Visual Studio 2017（Microsoft Build Tools 2015 でも可）をダウンロードしてきてインストールしてください。